# How to generate 1000 random vertices and edges in Python?

Tags: python, random, graph, minimum-spanning-tree

I need to generate 1000 vertices and edges, where the edges have different weights and all the vertices are connected to each other as shown in the image.
[image]

The output of the code should be represented in numerical values, like
(0, 1, 10)  <--point 0 to point 1 and the weight of the edge is 10.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you're trying to do?
Random vertices and edges will not look as nice as the picture you posted without additional constraints.
Where is you problem? representing the edges? drawing them randomly? Do you have any code (even pseudo code) to share?

Comment: I am working on My problem is generating

Answer (score 1):

You could create random vertices using Numpy and then triangulate them using SciPy's Delaunay algorithm:

```
import np
n = 1000 # number of vertices
v = np.random.rand(n, 2)

from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
tri = Delaunay(points)

# for each triangle you can get the edges
print(tri.simplices)
```

Now try to find the unique edges and enumerate them. The weights can be calculated using e.g. `np.linalg.norm`